# UIDocument synchronous read - completion handler stalled in dispatch

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, synchronous, uidocument

I tried multiple ways of wrapping a file read within a synchronous method call (including using multiple queues, specifying target queues, setting up an NSThread and signalling with NSCondition's, even moving the allocation of the UIDocument to the background thread in the end, and also trying dispatch_sync on the background queue as well).

What ended up consistently happening is the completion handler for UIDocument.openWithCompletionHandler wasn't executing, although the documentation indicates that shall happen on the same queue that initiated the openWithCompletionHandler call.

I figured this has ultimately something to do with the control not being returned by the outer/top-level method call to the run loop. It would seem that regardless of what other queues or threads are being set up, the dispatch system expects me to return from the outermost method call, or things get blocked. This would however defeat the whole synchronous design approach.

My use case requires synchronous file reads (with very small data sizes), and I'd prefer the convenience of UIDocument over moving to lower level methods, or looking at ways to introduce async patterns. I reckon UIDocument was designed for more conventional cases, I understand well enough the ubiquity - and in most cases user friendliness and efficiency of async patterns, but in this case it would present a cumbersome situation for both development and user experience.

I wonder if there is something else that could be tried with dispatch queues that could still be explored (like manually consuming events from a queue, creating a custom run loop) that could avoid this seemingly global synchronization effect.

EDIT: this is for an Audio Unit app extension. Instantiation is controlled by the platform, and a "half-initialized" state could become a problematic situation. It is pretty much standard in the industry to fully load the plugin before even allowing the host app to start playing any audio for example, not to mention starting to stream MIDI/automation events. (That's not to say there aren't extensions with crazy load times that could take another look at their design, but in most cases these are well justified in this domain).

Comment: You really shouldn't fight it. If you are supporting iOS 13+ you will soon be able to use Async/Await for simpler Async semantics. Your problems is that you are almost certainly going to end up blocking the main thread if you try and make everything synchronous. Ultimately you need to get your data back to the main queue.  You can't dispatch synchronously on the main queue, so that part will have to be Async. If that is Async then you might as well just do it the right way and wait for the completion.